# PictureBox zoom miscalculation

Tags: c#, zooming, picturebox, mousewheel

I am attempting to zoom in a picturebox using the mousewheel.
Using the following variables:

```
public static int offsetX = 0;
public static int offsetY = 0;
public static double scale = .05;
```

I draw a series of polygons to the picture box. However, I wanted the bottom left corner to refer to 0,, so I draw everything to the form with a -y. The drawn points have been affected by the above variables but the real points stay the same.

```
void pictureBox1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Delta > 0)
        scale += .025;
    else
        scale -= .025;

    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

When the mousewheel is moved forward I increase the scale variable and the box is refreshed. It is repainted using this code in the picturebox paint method:

```
     Graphics g = e.Graphics;
     foreach (Member m in activeTruss.members)
     {

        if (m.Visible == true)
        {
           Point[] pointArray = new Point[m.poly.Points.Count()];
           int index = 0;

           foreach (System.Windows.Point p in m.poly.Points)
           {

              pointArray[index].X = (int)((p.X + offsetX) * scale);
              pointArray[index].Y = (int)-((p.Y + offsetY) * scale);
              index++;
           }

           SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(m.color);
           g.FillPolygon(myBrush, pointArray);
        }
     }
```

it zooms the correct amount, however it appears to zoom towards the upper left corner because the offsets stay the same. The opposite is true when zooming out. How should I edit the offsets as I turn the mouse wheel in order to zoom directly towards the point under my mouse?

Comment: +1, negative votes are a bit harsh on this question, even without the code the concept of centering is universal given what's already provided in the question

Comment: The `f` on scale is unnecesary and just adds more commands to the compiled code. (The cast of single [float] to double)

Comment: Thanks Cole, that was a piece of leftover code that I had forgotten from when it was a float.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center your zoom

```
double offsetX = scale/2
double offsetY = scale/2
```

*Update*

To answer your second part about flipped picture, it sounds like you are not making a distinction on the x,y of your picture vs the x,y screen coordinates. Usually, screen coordinates start on the top of the screen, so top left is 0,0, however when you draw your picture, your picture's 0,0 is on the bottom left so you use -y. What you want to do is to start drawing from 0,0 to 0,MAXY without the flip. For this implementation detail, your code would help alot hehe :)

Comment: This may work with code I posted above. however I have other complications such as everything drawn to the picturebox is flipped. should I add that information and code to the question or detail it in a comment like this?

Comment: add it to your question, i may not be able to help if it has to do with your third party rendering software... so good for everyone to see